# Rotate an image on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to rotate an image on HTML5 canvas like this: http://webutils.co.uk/code/awc-image-rotater

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

I have been trying like this:

```
ctx3.drawImage(img3, -235, -142, 128, 128);  
ctx3.translate(151, 142);
ctx3.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
```

But really not fulfilling my requirement. Any help will deeply appreciated.

Comment: http://webutils.co.uk/code/awc-image-rotater this is exact link...

Comment: You can edit your question for things like that, just click the "edit" link

Comment: There are a half-dozen questions here on StackOverflow about rotating images in HTML5 canvases (see the "Related" list on the right). None of them addresses what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the translation and rotation *before* you draw the image. You set the context to its rotated and translated position, then you do the drawing in that translated and rotated state.

You can see in the example that you linked to:

```
this._rotate_canvas( deg, [Tx, Ty] );
this._context.drawImage( this._img_copy, this._overflow_x, this._overflow_y, this._image_width, this._image_height );

_rotate_canvas: function( deg, aPoint )
{
    this._context.translate( aPoint[0], aPoint[1] );
    this._context.rotate( this.deg2rad(deg) );
    this._context.translate( -aPoint[0], -aPoint[1] );
}
```