# Advise on Implementing card game on html

Tags: html

I am looking to implement a card based game (much like yu-gi-oh) of Game of Thrones. I am not new to programming I have a good level in Java, C, C++, but I am fairly new to html and its libraries. I wanted to know if anyone could give me some advises on which libraries or methods should I use. 
I will need to be able to:

- Have a large data base.
- Make little animations, just little translations and rotations of an image.
- Add personalized buttons and other menu items.
- Duels between players and multiplayer to 5 persons.

I Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For database you should use PHP + MySQL.

For animations use javascript with jquery library,HTML5,CSS3.

Personalized buttons,other menu items probably CSS-CSS3

Duels between players and multiplayer to 5 persons,umm probably use NodeJS,but it can be done in PHP+Ajax.

Or you can write it in Java,and embed it into a website.
Check Drakensang online,written in Java ,embededd into a website.

Good website for learning web development: http://www.w3schools.com/

Ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Jquery: jquery.com/

PHP: php.net/manual/en/index.php

NodeJS: nodejs.org/

MySQL: www.mysql.com/

Comment: Thank you! Just what I wanted

Answer (score -1):

Just use html5 and you will be fine. If you need more then jquery is probably useful.

In more detail:

- little animations, translations and rotation: [rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756287/rotate-an-image-on-html5-canvas)
- personalized buttons: normal grafic or css
- for multiplayer, you probably need sockets too. Those are also supported in html5.